# ex19 from learn c the hard way. error: ‘MapProto’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

I have the following files:
ex19.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "object.h"
#include "ex19.h"
//#include "gamemechanics.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // simple way to setup the randomness
    srand(time(NULL));

    // make our map to work with
    Map *game = NEW(Map, "The Hall of the Minotaur.");

    /*printf("You enter the ");
    game->location->_(describe)(game->location);

    while(process_input(game)) {
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

gamemechanics.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "ex19.h"
#include "object.h"
//#include "gamemechanics.h"

int Monster_attack(void *self, int damage)
{
    Monster *monster = self;

    printf("You attack %s!\n", monster->_(description));

    monster->hit_points -= damage;

    if(monster->hit_points > 0) {
        printf("It is still alive.\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("It is dead!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int Monster_init(void *self)
{
    Monster *monster = self;
    monster->hit_points = 10;
    return 1;
}

Object MonsterProto = {
    .init = Monster_init,
    .attack = Monster_attack
};


void *Room_move(void *self, Direction direction)
{
    Room *room = self;
    Room *next = NULL;

    if(direction == NORTH && room->north) {
        printf("You go north, into:\n");
        next = room->north;
    } else if(direction == SOUTH && room->south) {
        printf("You go south, into:\n");
        next = room->south;
    } else if(direction == EAST && room->east) {
        printf("You go east, into:\n");
        next = room->east;
    } else if(direction == WEST && room->west) {
        printf("You go west, into:\n");
        next = room->west;
    } else if(direction == SOUTHWEST && room->southwest) {
        printf("You go southwest, into:\n");
        next = room->southwest;
    } else if(direction == NORTHEAST && room->northeast) {
        printf("You go northeast, into: \n");
        next = room->northeast;
    } else if(direction == NORTHWEST && room->northwest) {
        printf("You go northwest, into: \n");
        next = room->northwest;
    } else if(direction == SOUTHEAST && room->southeast) {
        printf("You go southeast, into: \n");
        next = room->southeast; 
    } else {
        printf("You can't go that direction.");
        next = NULL;
    }

    if(next) {
        next->_(describe)(next);
    }

    return next;
}


int Room_attack(void *self, int damage)
{
    Room *room = self;
    Monster *monster = room->bad_guy;

    if(monster) {
        monster->_(attack)(monster, damage);
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("You flail in the air at nothing. Idiot.\n");
        return 0;
    }
}


Object RoomProto = {
    .move = Room_move,
    .attack = Room_attack
};


void *Map_move(void *self, Direction direction)
{
    Map *map = self;
    Room *location = map->location;
    Room *next = NULL;

    next = location->_(move)(location, direction);

    if(next) {
        map->location = next;
    }

    return next;
}

int Map_attack(void *self, int damage)
{
    Map* map = self;
    Room *location = map->location;

    return location->_(attack)(location, damage);
}


int Map_init(void *self)
{
    Map *map = self;

    // make some rooms for a small map
    Room *hall = NEW(Room, "The great Hall");
    Room *throne = NEW(Room, "The throne room");
    Room *arena = NEW(Room, "The arena, with the minotaur");
    Room *kitchen = NEW(Room, "Kitchen, you have the knife now");
    Room *bathroom = NEW(Room, "The bathroom, place where people shit");
    Room *playroom = NEW(Room, "A child's playroom");
    Room *dungeon = NEW(Room, "The dungeon with the witch");
    Room *jail = NEW(Room, "The jail with crooked criminals");

    // put the bad guy in the arena
    arena->bad_guy = NEW(Monster, "The evil minotaur");
    //ashwini is adding a new monster
    dungeon->bad_guy = NEW(Monster,"Witch");
    dungeon->bad_guy->hit_points = 20;

    // setup the map rooms
    hall->north = throne;

    throne->west = arena;
    throne->east = kitchen;
    throne->south = hall;

    arena->east = throne;
    kitchen->west = throne;

    //ashwini's addition to the map
    throne->northeast = dungeon;
    kitchen->north = dungeon;
    dungeon->southwest = throne;
    dungeon->south = kitchen;
    dungeon->east = jail;

    throne->northwest = jail;
    arena->north = jail;
    jail->southeast = throne;
    jail->south = arena;
    jail->east = dungeon;

    throne->southeast = playroom;
    kitchen->south = playroom;
    playroom->north = kitchen;
    playroom->west = hall;
    playroom->northwest = throne;

    throne->southwest = bathroom;
    arena->south = bathroom;
    bathroom->northeast = throne;
    bathroom->north = arena;
    bathroom->east = hall;

    // start the map and the character off in the hall
    map->start = hall;
    map->location = hall;

    return 1;
}

Object MapProto = {
    .init = Map_init,
    .move = Map_move,
    .attack = Map_attack
};



int process_input(Map *game)
{
    printf("\n> ");

    char ch = getchar();
    getchar(); // eat ENTER

    int damage = rand() % 4;

    switch(ch) {
        case -1:
            printf("Giving up? You suck.\n");
            return 0;
            break;

        case 'n':
            game->_(move)(game, NORTH);
            break;

        case 'N':
            game->_(move)(game,NORTHEAST);
            break;

        case 's':
            game->_(move)(game, SOUTH);
            break;

        case 'S':
            game->_(move)(game,SOUTHWEST);
            break;

        case 'e':
            game->_(move)(game, EAST);
            break;

        case 'E':
            game->_(move)(game,SOUTHEAST);
            break;

        case 'w':
            game->_(move)(game, WEST);
            break;

        case 'W':
            game->_(move)(game,NORTHWEST);
            break;

        case 'a':

            game->_(attack)(game, damage);
            break;

        case 'l':
            printf("You can go:\n");
            if(game->location->north) printf("NORTH(n)\n");
            if(game->location->south) printf("SOUTH(s)\n");
            if(game->location->east) printf("EAST(e)\n");
            if(game->location->west) printf("WEST(w)\n");
            if(game->location->northeast) printf("NORTHEAST(N)\n");
            if(game->location->northwest) printf("NORTHWEST(W)\n");
            if(game->location->southeast) printf("SOUTHEAST(E)\n");
            if(game->location->southwest) printf("SOUTHWEST(S)\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("What?: %d\n", ch);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

ex19.h

```
#ifndef _ex19_h
#define _ex19_h

#include "object.h"

struct Monster {
    Object proto;
    int hit_points;
};

typedef struct Monster Monster;

int Monster_attack(void *self, int damage);
int Monster_init(void *self);

struct Room {
    Object proto;

    Monster *bad_guy;

    struct Room *north;
    struct Room *south;
    struct Room *east;
    struct Room *west;
    struct Room *southwest;
    struct Room *southeast;
    struct Room *northeast;
    struct Room *northwest;
};

typedef struct Room Room;

void *Room_move(void *self, Direction direction);
int Room_attack(void *self, int damage);
int Room_init(void *self);


struct Map {
    Object proto;
    Room *start;
    Room *location;
};

typedef struct Map Map;

void *Map_move(void *self, Direction direction);
int Map_attack(void *self, int damage);
int Map_init(void *self);

#endif
```

object.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "object.h"
#include <assert.h>

void Object_destroy(void *self)
{
    Object *obj = self;
    assert(obj != NULL);
    if(obj) {
        if(obj->description) free(obj->description);
        free(obj);
    }
}

void Object_describe(void *self)
{
    Object *obj = self;
    assert(obj!=NULL);
    printf("%s.\n", obj->description);
}

int Object_init(void *self)
{
    // do nothing really
    return 1;
}

void *Object_move(void *self, Direction direction)
{
    printf("You can't go that direction.\n");
    return NULL;
}

int Object_attack(void *self, int damage)
{
    printf("You can't attack that.\n");
    return 0;
}

void *Object_new(size_t size, Object proto, char *description)
{
    assert(description != NULL);
    // setup the default functions in case they aren't set
    if(!proto.init) proto.init = Object_init;
    if(!proto.describe) proto.describe = Object_describe;
    if(!proto.destroy) proto.destroy = Object_destroy;
    if(!proto.attack) proto.attack = Object_attack;
    if(!proto.move) proto.move = Object_move;

    // this seems weird, but we can make a struct of one size,
    // then point a different pointer at it to "cast" it
    Object *el = calloc(1, size);
    assert(el!=NULL);
    *el = proto;

    // copy the description over
    el->description = strdup(description);

    // initialize it with whatever init we were given
    if(!el->init(el)) {
        // looks like it didn't initialize properly
        el->destroy(el);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        // all done, we made an object of any type
        return el;
    }
}
```

object.h

```
#ifndef _object_h //this is if note defined
#define _object_h //checks if there is alread an object_h
//above is usefule if we are including it multiple times, it doesn't reinclude,
//just does it once and keeps refereing back

typedef enum {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTHWEST, NORTHWEST, SOUTHEAST,NORTHEAST
} Direction;

typedef struct {
    char *description;
    int (*init)(void *self);
    void (*describe)(void *self);
    void (*destroy)(void *self);
    void *(*move)(void *self, Direction direction);
    int (*attack)(void *self, int damage);
} Object;

int Object_init(void *self);
void Object_destroy(void *self);
void Object_describe(void *self);
void *Object_move(void *self, Direction direction);
int Object_attack(void *self, int damage);
void *Object_new(size_t size, Object proto, char *description);

#define NEW(T, N) Object_new(sizeof(T), T##Proto, N)
#define _(N) proto.N

#endif
```

I am trying to make it so that ex19.c uses functions and structs from gamemechanics.c. But whenever I try to compile I get the following error:

```
    :~/c_learning/ex19_folder$ gcc -c ex19.c gamemechanics.c object.c
In file included from ex19.c:6:0:
ex19.c: In function ‘main’:
ex19.c:17:21: error: ‘MapProto’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     Map *game = NEW(Map, "The Hall of the Minotaur.");
                     ^
object.h:26:41: note: in definition of macro ‘NEW’
 #define NEW(T, N) Object_new(sizeof(T), T##Proto, N)
                                         ^
ex19.c:17:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
     Map *game = NEW(Map, "The Hall of the Minotaur.");
                     ^
object.h:26:41: note: in definition of macro ‘NEW’
 #define NEW(T, N) Object_new(sizeof(T), T##Proto, N)
                                         ^
```

My question is really how do I start to figure out what is really happening because at this point i'm just doing a mix and match just to see what makes it work but that doesn't help me understand why the error is happening (and because it always fails).  So to start off why do I get an error for MapProto being undeclared even though I declared in gamemechanics.c?.  I tried creating the gamemechanics.h but then I get confused with how the dependencies will work.  This is ex19 from learn c the hard way.  I can try doing things like creating a gamemechanics.h that creates function prototypes but then I get confused as to how it should be implemented in the system.  Any advice will be helpful. Also advice on how to make this question easier to understand will also be helpful.

Comment: are they all in the same folder?

Comment: yes they are all in the same folder

Comment: *"Also advice on how to make this question easier to understand will also be helpful."* Answer: by asking a clear question at the top of the wall of code.

Comment: *"My question is really how do I start to figure out what is really happening because at this point i'm just doing a mix and match just to see what makes it work but that doesn't help me understand why the error is happening (and because it always fails)."* Answer: By examing each line, line by line, from the first statement in `main`.

Comment: Let me rephrase I am having a hard time understanding why I am getting the error, because in main all I did was call: Map *game = NEW(Map, "The Hall of the Minotaur.");  So to attack the first error why does it say MapProto is undeclared.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler is parsing *ex19.c*, all it knows about are the items declared in

- the standard headers
- object.h
- ex19.h
- ex19.c

because those are the only files referenced by *ex19.c*.  Even though you've specified *gamemechanics.c* on the command line, the compiler won't look at that file while it's compiling *ex19.c*.

If you want the compiler to know about `MapProto` while it's compiling *ex19.c*, then you need to create a *gamemechanics.h* and include that file in *ex19.c*

The declaration that you need in *gamemechanics.h* is

```
extern Object MapProto;
```

Comment: Thank you! This totally solved my problem!!! What exactly is extern doing here?  My understanding is it says there is a variable somewhere else called Object MapProto and it is up to the linker to figure out how to save it in memory, so its more like a placeholder saying there is something called MapProto some where, is this correct interpretation?

Comment: @ahat Yes, your interpretation is correct. The `extern` keyword is used to let the compiler know that a variable exists in one of the other source files.